# Time calculator - a tool to compute the days between two dates

Tags: windows, osx, time-management, calculator

I frequently need a tool to calculate how many days from a date to another, for example from 27 April 2016 to 18 July 2016.

Are there tools for Windows or for OS X?

Answer (score 3):

On OS-X you already have python installed *and on windows it is easily [installed](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)* so you can simply do it on the command line, from your example:

```
>python -c"import datetime as dt;d=dt.date(2016,7,18) - dt.date(2016,4,27);print d.days"
82
```

You can even get time involved, e.g.:

```
>python -c"import datetime as dt;d=dt.datetime(2016,7,18,16,30) - dt.datetime(2016,4,27,20,43);print d"
81 days, 19:47:00
```

*If you are using python 3 you need to make the prints functions.*
Obviously you can put things into python scripts for more power and flexibility.

See the online [manuals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.timeanddate.com/date/duration.html has a nice UI, friendly and useful but it requires internet connectivity..

[image]